# findViewById not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

findViewById not working in fragment Here Iam Trying to add an listview to the specific fragment But i can't map the listview control using find viewBy Id
I am beginner to the android development I have no idea about implement the fragment
Can anyone help me ?

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

public FindPeopleFragment(){}
private static final String TAG = "CardListActivity";
private CardArrayAdapter cardArrayAdapter;
private ListView listView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

    return rootView;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.card_listView);

    listView.addHeaderView(new View(this));
    listView.addFooterView(new View(this));

    cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_card);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Card card = new Card("Card " + (i+1) + " Line 1", "Card " + (i+1) + " Line 2");
        cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
    }
    listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);


}
public class CardArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
    private static final String TAG = "CardArrayAdapter";
    private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public class CardViewHolder {
        TextView line1;
        TextView line2;
    }

    public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Card object) {
        cardList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.cardList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Card getItem(int index) {
        return this.cardList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        CardViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new CardViewHolder();
            viewHolder.line1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line1);
            viewHolder.line2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line2);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (CardViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Card card = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.line1.setText(card.getLine1());
        viewHolder.line2.setText(card.getLine2());
        return row;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_card);
Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your oncreateview should be like below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);



    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);

    listView.addHeaderView(new View(this));
    listView.addFooterView(new View(this));

    cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_card);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Card card = new Card("Card " + (i+1) + " Line 1", "Card " + (i+1) + " Line 2");
        cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
    }
    listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Do it

```
  listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);
```

and move

```
  return rootView;
```

at last `onCreateView(...)`

### Corrected:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {


View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);
listView.addHeaderView(new View(getActivity()));
listView.addFooterView(new View(getActivity()));
............
return rootView;

}
```

and also you should change

```
  listView.addHeaderView(new View(this));
  listView.addFooterView(new View(this));
```

to

```
  listView.addHeaderView(new View(getActivity()));
  listView.addFooterView(new View(getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragment does not have findViewById(). You have to use View object to access that method in Fragment (In your case "rootView"). If you are using Activity than you can directly use findViewById() because Activity have that method.

Update your a line in your code as below, it will make it working.

```
listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);
```

At end of onCreateView() add below line.

```
return rootView;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);


    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);

    listView.addHeaderView(new View(this));
    listView.addFooterView(new View(this));

    cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_card);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Card card = new Card("Card " + (i+1) + " Line 1", "Card " + (i+1) + " Line 2");
        cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
    }
    listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);

   return rootView;

}
```